# RibbonUI checkbox alignment

Tags: .net, xml, ms-office, ribbon, ribbon-control

I have ribbon tab with controls (2 buttons and 2 check boxes):
[image: Sample]

and code:

```
  <ribbon>
<tabs>
  <tab idMso="TabMessage" insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard">
    <group id="Group" insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard" label="lable">
      <toggleButton id="btn1" onAction="Click" label="Btn1" screentip="button" size="large" getImage="GetImage" />
      <toggleButton id="btn2" onAction="Click2" label="Btn2" screentip="button2" size="large" getImage="GetImage" />
      <checkBox id="checkbox1" label="CheckBox1" screentip="CheckBox1" onAction="CheckBox1_Click" />
      <checkBox id="checkbox2" label="CheckBox2" screentip="CheckBox2" onAction="CheckBox2_Click" />
    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
```

I need vertical align of check boxes to the center of ribbon tab.
I can add one more check box in top and make it invisible, but maybe there is more proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding `centerVertically="true"` to group tag.